# KNN using Mahalanobis distance gives low score

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-nn

I want to get average score of all possible K but the average accuracy I'm getting is much lower than what's given to me.

```py
avg_acc = 0
best_acc = 0
for i in range(1, 10):

    avg_k_acc = 0
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(
        x,
        y,
        random_state=50,
        test_size=i * 0.1
    )
    for k in range(1, len(X_train)):
        clasifier = KNeighborsClassifier(
            n_neighbors=k,
            algorithm='brute',
            metric='mahalanobis',
            metric_params={
                'VI': np.cov(np.linalg.inv(np.cov(X_train.T)), rowvar=False)
            }
        )
        clasifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
        y_pred = clasifier.predict(X_test)
        for z in y_pred:
            if z == 0:
                z = 1
            else:
                z = 0     
        cm = confusion_matrix(Y_test, y_pred)    
        acc = f1_score(Y_test, y_pred)
        avg_k_acc = acc + avg_k_acc

        avg_k_acc = avg_k_acc / len(X_train)
        avg_acc = avg_acc + avg_k_acc

print(avg_acc / 9)
```